# Where should the datatool package be loaded?

Tags: unicode-math, datatool

Trying to build the following MWE fails (at least here: TL2019, lualatex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\usepackage{datatool}%<-- loading the package here seems to be fine
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\usepackage{datatool}%<-- loading the package here, fails with errors

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb{myDB}{\jobname.csv}
    \noindent
    \DTLdisplaydb{myDB}
\end{document}
```

As a workaround I just moved the `\usepackage{datatool}` before the `\setmathfont` command. Is this safe? Or does this potentially cause other sideeffects in the future?

Comment: datatool loads amsmath, and amsmath should (currently) be loaded before unicode-math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your explaination is fine for me. Should I delete this trivial seeming question? Or would you like to answer (I would accept it).

Comment: Unless it's a duplicate, this seems valuable information that would deserve an answer in my opinion (even a short one). Especially if there is a typical error message, so that people Googling for the message can find the info.